# "Almost" a list coloring of $L(K_n)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n> 3$. We let $L_n$ be the set of $2$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, that is $L_n = \big\{\{a,b\}: a,b\in \{1,\ldots,n\} \land a<b\big\}.$

We say a map $c:L_n\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a *coloring*  if $l_1\neq l_2\in L_n$ and $l_1\cap l_2\neq \emptyset$ imply that $c(l_1)\neq c(l_2)$. It is not hard to prove that there is no coloring $c:L_n\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $c(l)\in l$ for all $l\in L_n$. If $c$ is a coloring, we call $l\in L_n$ *exceptional* if $c(l) \notin l$.

What is the minimum number of exceptional members of $L_n$ that a coloring $c:L_n\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ can have, in terms of $n$?

Comment: If $n\le 3$, there might be no exceptional member. Btw, you could say that you are looking for an edge-coloring of the complete graph.

Comment: Right, for $n\leq 3$ there is no exceptional member for some colorings.

Comment: Pushing domotorp's comment further, you want to delete boundedly many exceptional edges from $K_n$, then orient the remainder such that no vertex has in-degree more than $1$.  This is clearly impossible.

Comment: Yes, Ben is right, please change the question back to its original form, where there was no $N_0$ and you asked for the dependence on $n$!

Comment: The original version also has an easy answer: if you have more than $n$ edges left then somebody is definitely going to have in-degree more than $1$.  So almost everything will have to be exceptional.